# How to update Expresso Store 2.5.1 to use Stripe TLS v1.2?

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway, stripe

As Stripe is upgrading TLS to v1.2 soon, how do we update Store to use the later version?

https://stripe.com/blog/upgrading-tls

Is it as simple as updating the Omnipay Stripe gateway code to a later version such as the one below I just found?

https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-stripe/releases/tag/v2.4.0

Thanks

Comment: I would also be interested in the answer to this if one ever comes... or have you managed to get to the bottom of it yourself? Thanks!

Comment: I would third this query. Seems off that there has been no updates from Store/Dev Demon on this

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to supporting TLS 1.2, generally this is a server-side change, not a script-based change. So there's no action needed on DevDemon's part. Simply ask your host if they support TLS 1.2.

(Also, Store does not use Stripe's PHP library - they make more "bare-metal" calls to the API.)

You can test it yourself by [following Stripe's notes here](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-stripe-integration-from-tls-1-0-to-tls-1-2#php).